# Is it possible to make a token that is unique to a pair of addresses?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, erc-721

As we know, each ERC721 token is unique in the sense that each of them is assigned to an address. I wonder if it is possible to go further and make tokens that is unique to a pair of addresses? i.e. the token can be seen as uniquely belonging to the relationship of two addresses.
This will be useful as it opens up scenarios where relations between people, or between transactions, can themselves be tokenized.

Comment: You can just set two addresses as "admin" (or whatever the name can be), and add a modifier that only allow these addresses to use the functions of the contract.

Comment: Will it be transferable?

Comment: As long as you support the functions and events in the definition of the standard, then your token will still be 'transferrable.' You can add functions/events/capabilities to a standard, but you can't neglect to implement the things in the standard. (Well, you can, but then all bets are off about support from various tools. The standard allows the tools to know how to handle a token--adding stuff doesn't change that.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here's an example in pseudocode:

```
findNFTFromAddresses(address1, address2)
    NFTID = sha3(min(address1, address2), max(address1, address2))
```

This is assuming an undirected graph. For a directed graph, use:

```
findNFTFromAddresses(address1, address2)
    NFTID = sha3(address1, address2)
```